# Why am I unable to install/search pygame package using Anaconda Navigator?

Tags: pygame, pycharm, anaconda

I have made environments on Anaconda Navigator with python 3.6 and 3.8 which I am using as interpreter in a project using PyCharm but I am unable to install/search the Pygame package on the Anaconda Navigator for these environments.
I have installed the package but I could not find anything on why I cannot install it using Anaconda Navigator!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one is consistently building that package for Conda. There was [an attempt to build it on Conda Forge](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/pull/13759), but it appears abandoned after it never successfully compiled for any platform. If you want a Conda version, drop a package request on [the conda-forge/staged-recipes Issue queue](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/issues).

For now, create a new environment, then install it via `pip`. Or use a YAML, like:

**pygame.yaml**

```yaml
name: pygame
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.8  # or whatever version you like
  - pip
  - pip:
    - pygame
```

**shell session**

```bash
## create environment
conda env create -f pygame.yaml
```

The package is provides wheels for most platforms, so should be a simple install. Otherwise, you may also need something like the `conda-forge::compilers` package.